# how to toggle the header menu on react if i have combined classes on css?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i'm trying to toogling my header menu but i get several errors when i run the app on my browser

CSS classes

```
@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .header__hamburger {
      display: block;
      position: fixed;
      top:30px;
      right: 20px;
  }

  .header__hamburger.active .header__hamburger-line:nth-child(2) {
     opacity: 0;
  }

  .header__hamburger.active .header__hamburger-line:nth-child(1) {
      transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
   }

   .header__hamburger.active .header__hamburger-line:nth-child(3) {
      transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
   }
}
```

```
@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .header__navcontainer {
      display: flex;
      margin-top: -400px;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      width: 75%;
      transition: 0.5s linear;
      opacity: 0;
  }

  .header__navcontainer.active {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      width: 75%;
      transition: 0.5s linear;
      opacity: 1;
      margin-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```
function AppHeader() {

    return (
        <header className={headerStyle.header}>
            <div className={headerStyle.header__content}>

                <nav className={headerStyle.header__navbar}>
                    <a>
                        <img className={headerStyle.header__logo} src={Logo} alt="Logo" />
                    </a>

                    <div className={headerStyle.header__hamburger}>
                        <span className={headerStyle.header__hamburgerline}></span>
                        <span className={headerStyle.header__hamburgerline}></span>
                        <span className={headerStyle.header__hamburgerline}></span>
                    </div>

                    <div className={headerStyle.header__navcontainer}>
                        <ul className={headerStyle.header__linkscontainer}>
                          ... 
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>

            </div>
        </header>
    );
}

export default AppHeader;
```

on js i can make it works but on react i don't get how to do it. Can someone give me some advice how to solve this?

i've tried to search different stuffs, on the net i see that someone advice to use useEffect hook, someone else useState, but in my case i don't get how to use them because i have the css classes combined for the animation (the hamburger become an X when clicking on it)

this is my script on JS that is work fine if i don't use react

```
const hamburger = document.getElementsByClassName('header__hamburger')[0];
const navMenu = document.getElementsByClassName('header__nav-container')[0];

hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navMenu.classList.toggle('active')
    hamburger.classList.toggle('active')
});

document.querySelectorAll(".header__link").forEach(n => n.addEventListener("click", () => {
    navMenu.classList.remove('active')
    hamburger.classList.remove('active')
}));
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: i'm getting the error that the classList is not is not found, it looks like that react can't find any reference to the classlist

i've added to the question also the code that i have on js, eventually how to implement that script to react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're importing classnames from your css and you're asking how to assign more than one of them to an element. In that case, you can just combine classes based on state

```
function AppHeader() {
    
    const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);

    // conditionally append the classname
    const hambClass = headerStyle.header__hamburger
        + (showMenu ? ' ' + headerStyle.active : '');
    // or install and use the 'classnames' package
    const navClass = classnames(headerStyle.header__hamburger, {
        [headerStyle.active]: showMenu,
    });

    const toggleMenu = () => setShowMenu(state => !state);

    return (
        <header className={headerStyle.header}>
            <div className={headerStyle.header__content}>
                <nav className={headerStyle.header__navbar}>
                    <a>
                        <img className={headerStyle.header__logo} src={Logo} alt="Logo" />
                    </a>

                    <div className={hambClass} onClick={toggleMenu}>
                        <span className={headerStyle.header__hamburgerline}></span>
                        <span className={headerStyle.header__hamburgerline}></span>
                        <span className={headerStyle.header__hamburgerline}></span>
                    </div>

                    <div className={navClass}>
                        <ul className={headerStyle.header__linkscontainer}>
                          ... 
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
}
```